# I need drop-downs on a record set parameter in a script tool

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcgis

I am currently working on making a Python script into a script tool in ArcGIS 10.1. I have a record set created based on a table template for the necessary items I need.  I prefer to have drop-downs for predetermined items the user can select rather than have users type in the factors.  I tried setting up attribute domains in the template table with the predetermined items I want to feed the tool but it did not work and still requires the user to type in the items.  Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Basically all I have done is set up an attribute domain on my template table to give it all the possible selections for each field in hopes the options would show up in a drop down when the template was used as a schema for the record set parameter.  This did not work though.

Answer (score 1):

With a regular script tool, you must set a filter with a list of values for the parameter, via the properties of the script tool. Open the properties of the script tool (or go through the Add Script wizard), click the Parameters tab and next to Filter, choose Value List in the drop-down list:

[image]

Click the button next to Value List and enter the values manually one by one. See a detailed explanation in the 'Filter' section of the [Setting script tool parameters](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Setting_script_tool_parameters/00150000000n000000/) page.

If you have many values, you might want to use a Python toolbox, where you can define the properties of your parameters entirely in your code. Turn your valid values into a Python list and use it to define the `.filter.list` property of the parameter. See an example under the 'Applying filters to a parameter' section of the [Defining parameters in a Python toolbox](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Defining_parameters_in_a_Python_toolbox/001500000028000000/) page.

Comment: I am unable to use python toolboxes with my version of Windows and ArcGIS (it crashes every time using one).  And as for your response about value lists, I know this is a possibility for strings but I have a complicated script that needs to create a dictionary from multiple items per input.  So I have it set up currently to draw from 3 strings per input which are then grouped together.  I would rather have drop downs for each item in the record set similar to the value list that strings allow in the parameter set up.  However, there is no option for value lists in record sets